# Provide arbitrary arguments to a snippet in UltiSnips

Tags: vimscript, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

There are numerous occasions where you might want to have another optional argument in your snippet. Lets say I want to have a numbered list for example. Preferably I'd call something like enum3 which would
generate this:

```
begin{enumerate} 
    \item  $1 
    \item  $2
    \item  $3
\end{enumerate}
$0
```

I'm able to get generate vim conventional placeholders like this:

```
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item <++> 
    \item <++>
    \item <++>
\end{enumerate}
```

However is there any more elegant way in ultisnips to give an arbitrary number of placeholders?

Comment: There is a way to do this in Ultisnips, although it requires writing a separate function in python. This [dynamic tabstop generation example](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/examples/tabstop-generation/README.md) is a good reference